# Not Found when using activity stream as front page with BuddyPress

Tags: theme-development, customization, buddypress, loop, framework

I'm trying to create a Thematic child theme that uses BuddyPress.

First, I tried using BuddyMatic -- which currently doesn't work with WP3.

Next, I tried the BuddyPress compatibility pack -- which totally works! Except for one thing: when I select "Activity Feed" as an option for the front page, I get a Not Found error. Going to /activity/, /groups/, /members/, and all other BuddyPress pages, however, works fine.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work, but it's a bit hacky. Essentially, I coped the index.php from activity into the the main index.php of my Thematic child theme, adding the Thematic actions afterwards. Same error persists if I leave it on "Activity Stream" for the front page, but when I return it to the default "Most recent posts", my modified index.php in the root takes over. I'll post my code in a few days if nobody answers my question with how I can get it to work through that option -- I'm building this as a high-end in-house repeated use theme, rather not resort to what I did.

(Redid as answer since no response.)